# R Neural Network Forecasting - Aspect of Randomness?

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting

I have been trying different methods of forecasting and stumbled upon the
    nnetar()
function in the forecast package of R. I soon quickly realized that while this does work to forecast, it gives me something different every time I run it. Could anybody help to explain why this happens? I thought I had a decent understanding of neural nets and I don't see what could make drastic differences in forecasts, unless the nnetar() function randomly selects the number of nodes or something. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20, by default, networks are trained with random starting values and then their predictions are averaged when you use the function.

Because the function uses random starting values for each run, the forecasts will be different for each call too.

**EDIT: new question from OP in the comments**

In order to control the function and get the same random starting values each time, you can simple use the function `set.seed()` with the value of your choice.

For example:

```
    set.seed(666)
    forecast(nnetar(...),...)

    set.seed(666)
    forecast(nnetar(...),...)

    set.seed(666)
    forecast(nnetar(...),...)
```

will give the same results every time you run it with this "seed" value (666). You have to run `set.seed(666)` before every run of the rest of you code of course.

**EDIT 2: new new question from OP in the comments**

In order to have 100 different networks to fit with random starting weights:

```
nnetar(...,repeats=100,...)
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid that? Other than run it a ton of times and take the mean forecast of it?

Comment: You can control that. I will post an edit so you know how to do it.

Comment: Would it work to run it say 100 times and take the mean of the results? Because while setting the seed works, it doesn't necessarily give me the best forecast.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to put a higher number of repeats.